# Moving an GCP project to its parent folder?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The project is structured in this way:

```
organization
└── group/
    └── subgroup/
       └── product/
          └── my-gcp-project
```

I want to move that project to its parent, the structure will then look like:

```
organization
└── group/
    └── subgroup/
       └── product/
       └── my-gcp-project
```

Is there a way of doing that by using the Python client library in GCP? If not python can it be done with some other SDK?

I see that it can be done with [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/moving-projects-folders?hl=pt-br#gcloud) here.

Answer (score 1):

To manage projects, use the Resource Manager SDK:

[Python Client for Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest)

The API is `move_project`:

[Class ProjectsClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsClient#google_cloud_resourcemanager_v3_services_projects_ProjectsClient_move_project)

Example code from the SDK:

```
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

def sample_move_project():
    # Create a client
    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = resourcemanager_v3.MoveProjectRequest(
        name="name_value",
        destination_parent="destination_parent_value",
    )

    # Make the request
    operation = client.move_project(request=request)

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")

    response = operation.result()

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to move a project within the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource hierarchy using the Google Cloud Client Libraries, including the Python client library. You can achieve this by utilizing the Cloud Resource Manager API, which provides the necessary methods for managing GCP projects programmatically.

Here's an example of how you can move a project using the Python client library:

```py
from google.cloud import resource_manager

def move_project(project_id, new_parent_id):
    client = resource_manager.Client()
    project = client.fetch_project(project_id)
    project.parent = "organizations/{}".format(new_parent_id)
    client.update_project(project)
    print("Project {} moved successfully to parent {}".format(project_id, new_parent_id))
```

In the above code snippet, the `move_project` function takes the `project_id` of the project you want to move and the `new_parent_id` of the desired parent within the resource hierarchy. The function fetches the project using the `fetch_project` method, updates the project's `parent` property to the new parent's ID, and then saves the changes using the `update_project` method.

You need to make sure you have the necessary permissions to move projects within your GCP organization.

Please note that moving a project in the GCP resource hierarchy can have implications on access control, billing, and other configurations associated with the project. It is essential to thoroughly understand the impact and consequences of moving a project before performing the operation.

Additionally, similar operations can also be achieved using other GCP SDKs or command-line tools like the gcloud command-line tool.

Comment: 'Client' object has no attribute 'update_project'

Comment: This answer uses an old version of the resource manager libraries `v1` but should still work. The current version is `v3`.